# How to make a reusable view cells for UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell ? I've tried to sublassing UIView for the cell but it's not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to reuse my UITableViewCell to my UICollectionViewCell.

Until now, I always use 2 xibs, 1 for `UITableViewCell` and 1 for `UICollectionViewCell` and I think it's kinda waste.

I've tried to subclassing `UIView` for the cell but it's not working.

Comment: Are they look alike or do they show the same content in a different way? That's can indeed be two different ways of handling it.

Comment: they show exactly same content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this is by using reusable views. Here is a Github project that can help: [NibDesignable](https://github.com/mbogh/NibDesignable/)

You can also do this without using the project I mentioned, but it does make it easier. You then create a UIView with a View nib and put all your UI into this as well as any code for setting the UI components. Then you create your UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell and then just use the view that you created. You can also use prototype cells in a Storyboard for CollectionView or TableView if you prefer.